# How can I open another vertical window (:vsp) on the left in vim?

Tags: vim, vi, editing

vim's `:vsp` command opens a window on right. Is there a way to open it on the left side of the screen?

Answer (score 25):

You have to do `:rightb vsp`. or `:bel vsp`.

The `rightb` and `bel[owright]` stands for right below. You can put any splitting command after it and it will split in that direction dependant on if v is in the splitting command.

There is also `:lefta vsp` and `:abo vsp`, if you want to make sure you split in the other direction and works in the same way as above.

Comment: Correct, but full versions `rightbelow` and `leftabove` are easier to remember.

Answer (score 11):

There is a setting you can add to vimrc:

```
set nosplitright
```

There are equivalent commands for :sp

```
set nosplitbelow
```

Answer (score 2):

The command `:vnew` opens a new window on the left side for me.